# How do I boot from a liveusb using qemu-kvm?

Tags: boot, usb-drive, qemu

I am trying to get qemu-kvm to boot from my live usb stick. Is this possible?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`qemu-kvm -hdb <device>`, where `<device>` is the USB stick (e.g. `/dev/sdb`), should do it (tested with Ubuntu 12.04 on an USB stick and it works).

You will need write permission to the device (i.e. be `root` or change its permissions).

Comment: Good answer. BTW if you need an easy interface to manage your VMs, give virt-manager a try.

Comment: Just as a hint: I tried VirtualBox instead of kvm to test my live usb stick, and it's A LOT faster. You have to use this command as root to create a vmdk file to be used in VirtualBox: `VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename .VirtualBox/HardDisks/usbdisk.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/sdb`

Comment: Just a small note to self here - use the disk/device node in `-hdb` (e.g. `/dev/sdb`); NOT the partition (as in `/dev/sdb4`)

Comment: In order to avoid a warning message 
WARNING: Image format was not specified for '/dev/sdb' and probing guessed raw. Automatically detecting the format is dangerous for raw images, write operations on block 0 will be restricted. Specify the 'raw' format explicitly to remove the restrictions.

you can specify options in this format:

`-drive file=/dev/sdb,format=raw,index=0,media=disk`
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47235461/how-to-resolve-specify-the-raw-format-explicitly-to-remove-the-restrictions)

Comment: It's just `kvm -hdb iso_file_or_thumb_drive_device_file` on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 28):

qemu-kvm has disappeared.  use the hint in [start qemu by giving it a path to a linux root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123152/start-qemu-by-giving-it-a-path-to-a-linux-root?rq=1) instead.  this means

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -usb -usbdevice disk:/dev/sdb
```

where /dev/sdb is your raw device (not partition) of the usb stick that you want to boot.

(however, as of 12/2014, it's been flaky for me.  booting ubuntu-gnome 14.10 results eventually in a kernel panic on a stick verified to boot just fine on the metal.)

/iaw

Comment: Thanks, needed this to auto boot a build of `bin-x86_64-efi/ipxe.usb` for a EFI boot, and it worked without issues so far.

Comment: Can you please update your answer? I got the following:
        `qemu-system-x86_64: -usbdevice disk:/dev/sdb: '-usbdevice' is deprecated, please use '-device usb-...' instead`

Comment: Instead of -usbdevice storage, you now have to use sonmething like: `-device usb-storage,drive=xxx -drive file=/dev/sdd,if=none,id=xxx`

Comment: @RememberMonica `qemu-x86_64 -device usb-storage,drive=/dev/sdb`
gives `qemu: unknown option 'device'`

Comment: @AnnoyinC this looks like you are using the wrong qemu binary - the binary should be called `qemu-system-x86_64`

Answer (score 8):

I don't know why exactly, but Renan's answer didn't quite work for me. KVM said to me it couldn't find a bootable drive (despite the usb partition being marked as such).

However I've found another solution. Get the USB device VendorID:ProductID with lsusb. Example:

```
$ lsusb
...
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0781:5406 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Micro U3
```

Pass that to KVM, and ask for the boot menu:

```
sudo  kvm -m 512 -smp 1 -drive file=/path/to/hardisk/file.img -usb \ 
-usbdevice host:0781:5406 -boot menu=on
```

Press F12 for the menu, choose the usb device,  it works. There's probably a way to command the usb boot without needing to call the boot menu, but I didn't find any in man kvm.

Comment: As for me, passing usb stick as a hdd drive works correctly for me, but passing usb stick as a usb device with -boot menu=on 1) in bios mode allow me to choose it, shows syslinux menu (I flashed archlinux iso to usb stick with dd) and it starts loading, but fails with
Waiting 30 seconds for device /dev/disk/by-label/ARCH_201903 ...
sd 2:0:0:0 [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0
Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
ERROR: '/dev/disk/by-label/ARCH_201903' device did not show up after 30 seconds
2) in uefi it fails

Answer (score 2):

I did this by first creating a guest using e.g. virt-manager, then editing the virsh config file to boot from USB:

1. Edit config file for the vm:

   ```
   # virsh edit TAILS
   ```
2. Delete the `<boot>` element from the `<os>` element.  (Leave the rest of the `<os>` element intact.)  You can't use `<boot>` here, because the boot order will be specified in step 4.
3. Get the vendor and product ID for the USB device that contains the live system:

   ```
   # lsusb -v | grep -E '\<(Bus|iProduct|bDeviceClass|bDeviceProtocol)' 2>/dev/null
   ```

   This produces output like:

```
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 090c:1000 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) Flash Drive
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  iProduct                2
```

The vendor ID is the first four hex digits after 'ID' on the first line, `090c` in this example.  Product ID is the last four hex digits after the colon, here `1000`.

4. In the virsh editor, add a `<hostdev>` element for your USB device, inside the `<devices>` element (which should already exist).  Detailed instructions/examples for this element are at https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsHostDev.  `lsusb` gives the values in hexadecimal, so use the `0x` prefix unless you want to convert the values for some reason.

```
<devices>
  <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='usb'>
    <source startupPolicy='mandatory'>
      <vendor id='0x090c'/>
      <product id='0x1000'/>
    </source>
    <boot order='1'/>
  </hostdev>
</devices>
```

5. Save and exit virsh editor, and boot the VM in the usual way.  (I'm using virt-manager, but a command-line boot uses the same config file.)

Answer (score 2):

To emulate USB storage, attached to an USB port, that can be inserted and removed and will be seen as an USB device instead of a SATA hard disk (like -hdb  does), use:

```
$ qemu-system-x86_64                                      \
    -device piix3-usb-uhci                                \
    -drive id=pendrive,file=<disk.img>,format=raw,if=none \
    -device usb-storage,drive=pendrive                    \
    -boot menu=on
```

Replace <disk.img> with some USB disk image. Then to connect and disconnect the pen drive while running the VM, on the running qemu instance console:

```
(qemu) device_del pendrive
(qemu) drive_add 0 id=pendrive2,if=none,file=<disk2.img>
(qemu) device_add usb-storage,drive=pendrive2
```

Reference: https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/USB

Comment: Edit: piix3-usb-uhci is too slow. Use qemu-xhci if you can. https://www.kraxel.org/blog/2018/08/qemu-usb-tips/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an *image* of a liveusb, instead of a physical USB stick, you can do that with

```
$ kvm -usbdevice disk:/path/to/liveusb.img -boot menu=on ...
```

Without "-boot menu=on", kvm will always prefer the hard drive that you set with "-drive" or "-hd[a|b|c|d]".