# Boot another computer's drive with QEMU

Tags: qemu, bootable, virt-manager

I recently installed a SSD on an old laptop and I kept the previous disk. Now I want to see if I left anything important there, so I put it into a USB to SATA cask and I'm trying to access my data. The OS there is a Debian installation with encrypted home directory using `ecryptfs`. I tried mounting my Private directory in my current laptop (also Debian) but couldn't, so I'll open another question for that.

What I want to know is how to tell QEMU, either via CLI or using `virt-manager`, to boot from the first partition on an USB drive, say `/dev/sdb1`, where the EFI directory of that system was. I've seen posts that deal with booting a USB Live Image created using `dd`, but I couldn't boot it. For example, when following the instructions [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37779/how-do-i-boot-from-a-liveusb-using-qemu-kvm) and [here](https://coderwall.com/p/1usy5a/test-your-bootable-usb-drive-with-qemu) I just got a screen stuck at "Booting from Hard Drive...", but nothing else happens.

Should the `/dev/sdb1` partition be mounted? Because I've tried it both ways, with the same result.

EDIT: Here's the partition table of the disk:

```
fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: 2115            
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 55BB5701-6D3C-4BAC-A3DF-A70D195D1B7A

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1        2048    1050623    1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sdb2     1050624 1911824383 1910773760 911.1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb3  1911824384 1953523711   41699328  19.9G Linux swap
```

Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: Besides installing the drive again on a computer, is there a way of telling whether this is what is happening? If I connect it with my USB cask, the OS will read the number of logical sectors from this device, so I do not see how to know if this number changed from the real one.

Comment: There are no changes in that regard; I'll post what `fdisk -l` tells me, in any case.

Comment: IMO the partition table makes sense and the problem I mentioned does not occur here.

Comment: Normally you do **not** boot from a partition, you boot from the disk: `qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -drive file=/dev/sdb,format=raw,media=disk`

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov: nope, it is still stuck at "Booting fom disk".